# Outlook Simplified Account Creation wizard doesn't perform autodiscover look up

Tags: outlook, single-sign-on, exchangeonline, office365, autodiscover

I was migrating users from Google G-Suite (Google Apps) to Office 365 Exchange Online using the following scenario:

- Keep MX records at Google for coexistence (accounts co-exist at both Google and M$)
- Change autodiscover.domain.tld record to point to `autodiscover.outlook.com` for Outlook auto configuration.
- Use `Active Directory SSO` (Pass-through authentication), so user's don't have to enter the username and password when creating a new account in Outlook. (Outlook was not previously installed)

I ran into the problem, where autodiscover look-up WON'T happen at all when running Outlook's `Simplified Account Creation` wizard. Instead, Outlook will prompt you with the authentication window for imap.gmail.com (Surprise!).

[image: Outlook Simplified Account Creation wizard]

After wasting hours of troubleshooting, I found this [article](http://masterandcmdr.com/outlook-autodiscover-weirdness/), which explains that **Outlook 2016 `Simplified Account Creation` doesn't perform autodiscover look-ups** (shocked?), instead it's using a service called `acompli.net` to determine your e-mail service provider. In this case, `acompli.net` looks up your MX records and returns Google as your current provider (which is incorrect and false behavior).

Many solutions suggest to disable Outlook 2016 `Simplified Account Creation` wizard. But doing so will disable automatic account creation and SSO, meaning that users will have to enter their username and password, as well as server name and other e-mail settings.

**The question is: How to force Outlook `Simplified Account Creation` wizard to point to Office 365?**

Answer (score 0):

Here is somewhat acceptable solution:

**Create an empty zone for acompli.net on your DNS servers**

In this case the `Simplified Account Creation wizard` fails to perform the lookup and brings up the list of providers. Users will be able to create an account without entering password, but they have to choose Office 365, which is the first choice.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned "migrating users from Google G-Suite (Google Apps) to Office 365 Exchange Online, Keep MX records at Google for coexistence " It looks more like co-existence. About migrating, you should 
Create a list of Gmail mailboxes to migrate, then create a migration batch on ECP, update your DNS records to route Gmail directly to Office 365. More details, you could refer to the link below:

**Migrate G Suite mailboxes to Office 365**

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mailbox-migration/migrating-imap-mailboxes/migrate-g-suite-mailboxes